# Видимость функции класса после её выполнения в другом файле

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Имеется файл `index.php` - точка входа. Далее в нём я пишу следующее:

```
class Loading {
  public function controller($vid, $data = array()) { 
    $file  = DIR_PATH . 'controllers/' . $vid. '.php';
    if(is_file($file)) {
        include_once($file);
    }
  }
}
```

Далее создаю в этом же файле `index.php` объект класса `Loading`:

```
$loading = new Loading();
```

Данная функция `controller` класса `Loading` создана для подключения файлов.

Затем ниже в `index.php` идет подключение файла `activ_controller.php`.

```
include "views/activ_controller.php";
```

В файле `activ_controller.php` я собственно подключаю нужный файл с помощью строки кода:

```
$data['file'] = $loading->controller('left');
```

Файл `left.php` успешно подключился, т.е. `$loading->controller('left')` отработал, но в нем уже не могу вызвать еще раз, например:

```
$loading->controller('new_file');
```

Пишет следующее:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: loading in E:\Programs\OpenServer\domains\...
```

Сам файл `left.php` пусть содержит следующий код:

```
<?php echo 'left.php'; ?>
```

Как можно это исправить подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что такое $data['file'] и откуда оно. Киньте полный код.

Comment: и почему вы думаете, что переменная, объявленная не пойми где, станет вдруг доступна внутри метода класса? Мб вам стоит пересмотреть логику в сторону статичных методов и синглтона?

Comment: @16artemiy16 Это полный код. `$data` является массивом, в него попадают результаты работы функций из подключаемых файлов, собственно как в движке opencart. Далее к этому массиву идет обращение по ключам.

Comment: @Дима это не полный код, а минимальная нарезка из него. Тут совершенно непонятно, на каком этапе, как именно и в какой области видимости создается $loading. Непонятно, откуда берется второй ее вызов и т.д. Идеальный вопрос, если собеседник телепат.

Comment: @teran Мне надо с этим сначала разобраться, понять, чтобы в дальнейшем не было подобного.

Comment: @rjhdby Ну собственно изменил вопрос, все как есть написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил следующим способом:

Прописал `$loading = new Loading();` повторно в файле `left.php` для того, чтобы повторно в `left.php` вызвать `$loading->controller('new_file');`.

Скажите, это правильно/допустимо?

Comment: да вроде правильно, только скажите плиз, зачем тут вообще нужен класс? можно же просто пользовательскую функцию описать, один раз её проинклудить, и вызывать сколько угодно раз.

Comment: @Эдуард Да, Вы правы, можно просто функцию)

Comment: @Эдуард Почему еще написал в классе, потому что в нем будут несколько функций, функция для подключении из контролера, вида, модели... Обращение пойдет по одному классу к конкретной функции.

Comment: ничего не мешает же написать сколь угодно функций в отдельном php-файле, и потом один раз подключить этот файл, и юзать необходимые его функции.

Comment: @Эдуард Тоже верно, но если программировать на ООП, то думаю правильнее в классе прописать функции.

Answer (score 0):

php.net:

> Выражение **include_once** включает и выполняет указанный файл во
>   время выполнения скрипта. Его поведение идентично выражению include, с
>   той лишь разницей, **что если код из файла уже один раз был включен,
>   он не будет включен и выполнен повторно и вернёт TRUE**. Как видно из
>   имени, он включит файл только один раз.

попробуйте либо возвращать результат include_once из $loading->controller, либо если вам это необходимо, используйте include

Comment: Вообще не понял! Покажите на примере моем, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте автозагрузчик для нужных классов

```
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
function autoload($name)
{
    $file = ROOTPATH . 'incfiles/classes/' . $name . '.php';
    if (file_exists($file))
        require_once($file);
}
```

Далее

```
new core();
```

Автоматом подключиться класс core из incfiles/classes/

Comment: На моём примере это возможно показать?

Comment: Разобрался, только что мне это даст?, ровно тоже, что и сейчас у меня. Сейчас у меня уже описан класс в index.php, ровно тоже будет, если подключить класс сюда же.

Answer (score 0):

**Твой вариант:**
Просто нужно создать объект класса и все, либо чуток переделать :)
Файл: `корень_сайта/index.php`

```
<?php
define('DOC_ROOT','..'.dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/');
class Loading {
    public function controller($vid, $data = array()){
        $vid .= (!stripos($vid,'.php'))?'.php':'';
        $file = DOC_ROOT.'controllers/'.$vid;
        if(is_file($file)) include_once $file;
        return basename($vid);
    }
}
$loading = new Loading();
include "views/activ_controller.php";
$loading->controller('new_file');
```

Файл: `корень_сайта/views/activ_controller.php`

```
<?php
$data['file'] = $loading->controller('left');
```

Файл: `корень_сайта/controllers/left.php`

```
<?php
$loading = new Loading();
$loading->controller('new_file');
```

Файл: `корень_сайта/controllers/new_file.php`

**Мой вариант:**
Файл: `корень_сайта/index.php`

```
<?php
include './config/packageClass.php';
include 'views/activ_controller.php';
Loading::controller('new_file');
```

Файл: `корень_сайта/views/activ_controller.php`

```
<?php
$data['file'] = Loading::controller('left');
```

Файл: `корень_сайта/controllers/left.php`

```
<?php
Loading::controller('new_file');    
echo '<br>Include file: '.__FILE__;
```

Файл: `корень_сайта/controllers/new_file.php`

```
<?php
echo '<br>Include file: '.__FILE__;
```

Файл: `корень_сайта/config/constants.php`

```
<?php
define('DOC_ROOT','..'.dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/');
//... Куча других констант
```

Файл: `корень_сайта/config/packageClass.php`

```
<?php
include_once 'constants.php';
$dir = DOC_ROOT.'config/packageClass';
$ext = 'php';
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD
);
if(is_array($ext)) $ext = implode('|',$ext);
$arr = iterator_to_array(new RegexIterator($Iterator, '#('.$ext.')#i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH));
foreach(array_keys($arr) as $v) include_once $v;
```

Файл: `корень_сайта/config/packageClass/loading.php`

```
<?php
class Loading {
    public static function controller($vid, $data = array()){
        $vid .= (!stripos($vid,'.php'))?'.php':'';
        $file = DOC_ROOT.'controllers/'.$vid;
        if(is_file($file)) include_once $file;
        return basename($vid);
    }
}
```

В папке: `корень_сайта/config/packageClass/` можно кидать разные классы и они будут подключатся все.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш вариант:)